# FTP close message while connecting FTP acount

Tags: visual-studio-code, ftp

I try to connect FTP in visual studio code with FTP-simple extension but the terminal shows the message as,
FTP - Connecting..
FTP - Close!!,
Please tell me a solution.

```
[
    {
        "name": "inventory",
        "host": "166.62.6.101",
        "port": 21,
        "type": "ftp",
        "username": "user@ims.asterpharmaceutical.com.pk",
        "password": "xxxxxxx",
        "path": "/",
        "autosave": true,
        "confirm": false
    }
]
```